# How to find LTFS Volume serial number instead of tape drive serial number

Tags: c#, console-application, wmi

I have an LTFS Tape mounted on my machine and I want to find its volume serial number programatically. I found that 'A00024' is that number by rightclick-->Properties-->LTFSDetails. I wrote a code to find it dynamically

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher ms = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in ms.Get())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("serial.No    " + mo["SerialNumber"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Name         " + mo["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Manufacterur " + mo["Manufacturer"]);
                Console.WriteLine("model        " + mo["Model"]);                
                Console.WriteLine("other info   " + mo["OtherIdentifyingInfo"]);
                Console.WriteLine("media type   " + mo["MediaType"]);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------");
            }            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

But the Serial number returned here is the tape drive serial number, which I think probably the serial number the manufacturer given to the hardware.Any idea how to find LTFS volume serial number

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a file copy software and LTFS-related tools of OS X for named "RapidCopy".

Volume serial information of LTFS not be able to easily access.
Information that your ask exists in the internal meta data of LTFS.
Please look at page 29 of the following pdf.
http://www.snia.org/sites/default/files/LTFS_Format_2.2.0_Technical_Position.pdf

Header structure of ANSI VOL1 has been published, but to access the data portion should require access to SCSI.
I'm reading some of the implementation of IBM LTFS, but it is unlikely be easy.